# Symfony: Get data content of array

Tags: php, symfony

I need to send an array of arrays like:

```
    $arrayData = array();
    $arrayIndex = array();
    $arrayUsnm = array();
    $arrayEmail = array();

    array_push($arrayIndex, $j+1);
    array_push($arrayUsnm, $userNameFromFile);
    array_push($arrayEmail, $eMailFromFile);
    $arrayData = [$arrayIndex, $arrayUsnm, $arrayEmail];
```

I send to the view like:

```
   'datas' => $arrayData,
```

But this is the collection of arrays inside of array:

```
    [["foo1,"foo2"],["bar1","bar2"],["fo1","fo2]]
```

In mi twig I have:

```
    {% for key in datas %}
    <ul>
        <td class="col-md-3">{{ key }}</li>
        <td class="col-md-3">{{ key }}</li>
        <td class="col-md-3">{{ key }}</li>
    </ul>
    {% endfor %}
```

How can I access to the first array, and the second, etc ?.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use another loop for your arrays in your loop:

```
{% for arr in datas %}
<ul>
    {% for key in arr %}
        <li class="col-md-3">{{ key }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endfor %}
```